# QueryString function......what does it do?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, query-string

I've become the editor of a website that i didn't create. There is a map feature on one of the webpages and i've been asked to alter how the map initially loads on the webpage.

I don't know if the javascript that i'm looking at is original or whether it's some stock code provided by someone like Google. Anyhow, some of the code that i'm looking at looks like this....

```
var gridChoice = "";
   if (osbounds) gridChoice = osbounds.gridStyle;
   var gridUse = QueryString("g");
   if (gridUse) gridChoice = gridUse;

   switch (gridChoice)
   ....
   ....
   ....
```

In the comments, it states that using g in the QueryString should override what ever the code does.

It selects the type of grid displayed on the map. There is another selection that is identical to this that selects the type of map shown (Eg. Google road, Terrain, Hybrid, etc). The code used to select the type of map uses m in the QueryString. With the same comment - that m should override.

I have no idea how QueryString works or or what it does. I've tried to Google it but i can only find people asking for advice on places like this. I can't seem to find any documentation that describes the function, and how it works. I know there will be something out there but my Google-foo is weak on this one.

May someone describe to me what it does? Or link a source that exlains it well please?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a part of basic JavaScript; if it's in use in the codebase you're looking at, you'll have to find the library it comes from.

Comment: seems like a function written to get url parameter . maybe . query string is used for that . look it up in the code and post the function here .

Comment: Look through the sources first and see if `QueryString` is defined by code that's part of the site. If not, then it must be coming from some imported library, so you'll want to look into each of those. Without more specific information (that only you have access to), all anybody can do is make a guess.

Comment: Thank you Pointy. I thought QueryString was a stock javascript function. Before posting the question, i did have a look around in the script that i found it in but couldn't see anything that popped up. I'll have a deeper dig in to the code and anything included and get back to you guys. 

@Jason - I appreciate the help you provided that is now deleted. But i don't appreciate your assumptions about myself, or the way you've publicly talked about me - a stranger that you don't even know. I hope you're not like this in the real world....

Comment: Ok, my bad. I must have woken up on the wrong side.

Comment: It is as Jason and saru95 described - Jason, why did you delete your answer? It uses location.search (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) So it turns out that querystring is the name for the part of the URL that represents the parameters of a webpage. In this application, the parameters would be...GPS coordinates, type of map, type of grid, etc. The input in to the function QueryString selects the parameter to be looked at. It then parses the URL for that parameter and then returns the appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

It uses location.search (w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) So it turns out that querystring is the name for the part of the URL that represents the parameters of a webpage. In this application, the parameters would be...GPS coordinates, type of map, type of grid, etc. The input in to the function QueryString selects the parameter to be looked at. It then parses the URL for that parameter and then returns the appropriate response.